# CSS Modules 'compose' keyword breaks

Tags: css, reactjs, vite, css-modules

### Issue

- When using `compose`, both the style that composes and the composed style seem to be duplicated and added multiple times. They end up overriding each other, and the composed style ends up being the last one added, rather than the composing style.
- An example:  Here the `subheader` should compose the `header` class and then override some of the styles from `header`.

  ```css
  .subheader {
  composes: header from './Checkout.module.css';
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 16px 0 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-bottom: none;
  }
  ```
- However, that doesn't happen. Only the styles in `header` are applied. And this is what the styles look like in the devtools. Can't post images, so [the screenshot is linked here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DEez.jpg).
- As you can see, both the classes are added multiple times, and override each other. And the class that we want to override, the `header` class, is added last and ends up being what is applied.

### Maybe Pertinent Information

- Using a Mac M1 Mini
- Using React 17.0.2
- Recently switched from `webpack` to `vite`